# How to put constructor expressions in an array an use them in C#?

Tags: c#

Suppose class `X` and `Y` are both inheriting from class `P` Suppose We have an array of constructor expressions (not sure what code for that is) of A and B so that (psudo code)

```
a[0] = new X();
a[1] = new Y();
```

How can we get : `P p = Execute(a[0]);`

Comment: Do you want to create instances on demand? If so - create a delegate/anonymous function that returns an instance, then call it. Eg: `a[0] = () => new X();` then `a[0]()`

Comment: @zerkms : yes, what I was doing was keeping instances, but what I really want is to create on demand only. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `Func<P>` delegate array for the constructors.  For example:

```
Func<P>[] a = new Func<P>[2];
a[0] = () => new X();
a[1] = () => new Y();
P p = a[0]();
```

The above example covers default constructor calls.  More complex constructor calls can be made by creating an object to hold constructor values and then changing the array to take the object.  For example, lets say there is a class Z with properties val1 and val2.  This can be done:

```
Func<Z, P>[] a = new Func<Z, P>[2];
a[0] = z => new X(z.val1, z.val2);
a[1] = z => new Y();
Z varZ = new Z(1, 2); // For example
P p = a[0](varZ);
P p1 = a[1](null);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could create an array of `Func<P>`s, like this:

```
var a = new Func<P>[2];
a[0] = () => new X();
a[1] = () => new Y();
var p = a[0]();
```

This assumes that the constructor methods are parameterless.

Answer (score 1):

Using reflection:

```
var types =
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(typ => typ.BaseType == typeof(P))
            .OrderBy(typ=>typ.Name)
            .Select(typ => typ.GetConstructors().First()).ToArray();

    var a = (P)types[0].Invoke(null);
    var y = (P)types[3].Invoke(null);
    var x = (P)types[2].Invoke(null);
    var b = (P)types[1].Invoke(null);
```

This will create an array filled with ConstructorInfo for each child class of P.

If you want to customly add each ConstructorInfo:

```
 var type = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetType("typeName").GetConstructors().First();
```

This is in the case when constructors are empty and public.